# View Custom Object Field on Account Layout

Tags: custom-object, lookup, page-layout, account

I've created a custom object, customObjectA. One of those fields in the object has a Account(lookup) and another text field, lets call it fieldA. I'd like to have fieldA appear on the Account layout page. Is it possible to do so? Do I need to create a lookup field or a formulary on the Account object to the customObjectA to display the data?

The reason I'm creating a custom object for this field is because I'd like the value of fieldA to be unique on a user-account level and not just on an account level. For instance account John Smith fieldA's value will be different based on the user who signs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a lookup field from customObjectA to Account creates a one-to-many relationship between Account & customObjectA, there is no way to "push" a field from customObjectA to Account - in the case where there are more than one customObjectA records for a given Account, there's no way to know which of the child record's values should go to Account.

You can write a trigger that has logic to determine the winning value to put onto Account, but can't do this declaratively.

Comment: Would adding the related list with that field as one of the columns suffice? Otherwise a trigger is the only real way.

Comment: So if a trigger needs be used, that means its not possible display something on the user-account level as I can only push one value to the account at a time?